# PYTHON: ValueError: unknown url type: 'comments_42.html'

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

Okay, so I am doing a course on Pyhton and the assignment asks us to retrieve data from an html document.
Here is what I came up with:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl


ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

intlist = list()
tot = 0
count = 0
url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    n = tag.contents[0]
    n = int(n)
    count += 1
    tot = tot + n
print("Count:", n)
print("Total:", tot)
```

And this is what happens when I try to access the file (NOTE: the file I am trying to retrieve is stored locally):

[image: traceback error]

What is the cause of this error?
Thanks anyone for the help.

Comment: you have the html stored in the local filesystem?

Comment: Well, what about a protocol? `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps` - just to name a few? Ortherwise just open the file via `with open(my_file) as file: `

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20558624/11213106

Comment: @bigbounty thats what the assignment asks you to do

Comment: @Jan tried it, didnt work

Comment: @SuryaGanesh tried that as well but it didnt work either

Comment: why are you trying to open a local file using `urlopen`, you can directly load it into `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: @Chase didnt know about that

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to read the html directly into `BeautifulSoup`. You cannot open a local file using `urlopen` as easily.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

with open('filename.html', 'r') as htmlfile:
    html = htmlfile.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Now it's loaded for you to parse, don't forget to change `filename.html` to your actual file path

Edit: There are also many more problems with your code. `soup('span')` does not find span elements. Please refer to the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for at least a basic understanding.